# How to store Image in Document directory and image path into database in ios?

Tags: ios

I have an NSMutableArray contain list of images selected from gallry in my app.
Array contain image information as below

AlbumImages(

```
"<UIImage: 0x7fe8a601bf60>, {4288, 2848}",
"<UIImage: 0x7fe8a3f04f10>, {3000, 2002}",
"<UIImage: 0x7fe8a3cb4710>, {1668, 2500}",
"<UIImage: 0x7fe8a3e05c20>, {3000, 2002}",
"<UIImage: 0x7fe8a3cb2e10>, {4288, 2848}",
"<UIImage: 0x7fe8a6125510>, {4288, 2848}"
```

)

Please suggest me how can i store this images into database.
I want to store image path into database table and store image into document directory

Comment: Store `images in document directory` and in `database` you can `store path`.

Answer (score 1):

**try**

```
for(int i=0;i<array.count;i++){

        NSString *docdirectoryPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents", NSHomeDirectory()];

        NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourimage, 0.8);

        NSString *imgPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/imagename%d.png", docdirectoryPath,i];
        [data writeToFile:imgPath atomically:YES];

        //here write your insert query below. and store imgPath in your database

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Create unique name for your image.
2 - Convert image into NSData object and call writeToFile method as

```
 NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents", NSHomeDirectory()];
 NSString *imgPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png", filePath, uniqueImgName];
[imgData writeToFile:imgPath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use core data, make the data attributes external and it will automatically externalize the stuff. no need to manually worry about names

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
          NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    /***************Save Image in Document Directory*****************/

        UIImage *img = [array objectAtIndex:i];

          NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img); //convert image into .png format.

          NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

          NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",TimeStamp]];


          [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];

          NSLog(@"image saved");
        /*****************************************************/
        /***************Save image in  Table*****************/

          NSString *query;

          query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into table_name values(null,'%@');",fullPath];

          //Execute the query.
          [self.dbManager executeQuery:query];
}
```